# Why do I need to cast methods to `Action` or `Func` to use it in value tuples?

Tags: c#, .net, tuples, c#-7.0, valuetuple

Why the compiler can't handle these `x3` and `x4` assignments?

```
    void X()
    {
        (Func<int, int>, int) x1 = (GetX, 1);           // OK
        object x2 = x1;                                 // OK
        object x3 = (GetX, 1);                          // Error CS8135 Tuple with 2 elements cannot be converted to type 'object'.
        object x4 = (GetX, 1) as (Func<int, int>, int); // Error CS8307 The first operand of an 'as' operator may not be a tuple literal without a natural type.
        object x5 = ((Func<int, int>, int))(GetX, 1);   // OK
        object x6 = ((Func<int, int>)GetX, 1);          // OK
    }

    int GetX(int x)
    {
        return x;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a tuple does not have concrete type unless you cast it to more specific type. Your `GetX` method might be convertible to various delegate types. So you will need to cast it to a specific one, compiler can't choose it for you.

The reason is similar to this case:

```
Delegate del = x => x * 2; // err
Delegate del2 = (Func<int,int>)(x => x * 2); // OK
```

Comment: I see now in Visual Studio, that when I point the mouse in the GetX token in these lines where there are errors, it shows "method group". I didn't realize that I can have a lot of overloads with different parameters and all of them are identified by the same name...